# Remove empty bars in grouped plotly express bar chart, such that the visual distance between each group of bars is equal

Tags: python, express, charts, plotly

I'm trying to group traces of a barchart and maintain the same distance between each group.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "City": ["Toronto", "Toronto", "Toronto", "CPH", "CPH", "London", "London"],
  "Tower name": ["T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6","T7"],
  "Height": [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0 ,5.0],
})

fig = px.bar(x=df['City'], y=df['Height'],color = df['Tower name'], color_discrete_sequence=['black'])
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

The result is as shown below.
[image: Result]

The solution I want is like this

[image: Desired Result]

I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54416061/remove-bars-with-0-height-in-a-bar-graph-in-dash) but the solution in that thread suggest stacking the bars, which is not a possibility in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple-categorical axes https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/#multicategorical-axes

```
go.Figure(go.Bar(x=df.loc[:,["City", "Tower name"]].T.values, y=df["Height"].values, marker_color="black"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thank you. 
A follow-up question: Would it be possible to remove the T1, T2, T3... etc marks and rotate the Toronto, CPH, London to be vertical when they get too close to each other (my real data set is significantly larger)

Comment: there are multiple restrictions on multi-category.  this technique https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#tickmode--array does not work for getting rid of T1,T2,...

Comment: Thank you rob. I have created a follow up question in a separate post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69767008/how-do-i-show-only-the-category-tick-and-rotate-them-of-a-multicategory-plotly