# How do I show only the category tick, and rotate them, of a multicategory plotly bar chart

Tags: python, plotly, plotly.graph-objects

1. I wish to NOT show the inner category label in a multi-catogory bar chart using plotly graph-objects
2. Further, I wish to rotate the label of the outer category label

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "City": ["Toronto", "Toronto", "Toronto", "CPH", "CPH", "London", "London"],
  "Tower name": ["T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6","T7"],
  "Height": [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0 ,5.0],
})

fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=df.loc[:,["City", "Tower name"]].T.values, y=df["Height"].values))
fig.show()
```

The code gives the following output:

[image: output]

Desired output is as shown below:

[image: desired output]

To hide the inner category I have tried to create an empty column in my data as follows, but that doesn't work

```
df['empty'] = ""
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=df.loc[:,["City", "Tower name"]].T.values, y=df["Height"].values))
fig.update_xaxes(ticktext = df['empty'])
fig.show()
```

to rotate the tickmarks I have used tickangle, but that only rotates the inner category. The city names remain unrotated

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=df.loc[:,["City", "Tower name"]].T.values, y=df["Height"].values))
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle = -90)
fig.show()
```

[image: output]

This is a follow-up questions to the thread: [Remove empty bars in grouped plotly express bar chart, such that the visual distance between each group of bars is equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69754693/remove-empty-bars-in-grouped-plotly-express-bar-chart-such-that-the-visual-dist)